# How to render nested list keeping only deepest level in front?

Tags: lists, enumerate, rendering

I want to have a nested list so that it would turn into:

[image]

[Original image](https://gist.github.com/OlegJakushkin/bbb51a4e019657e9cbc24616a0fe3578) was rendered using [WaveJSON](https://github.com/wavedrom/wavedrom) that looked like this:

```js
{signal: [
  {    name: 'clk'},
  ['Master',
    ['ctrl',
      {name: 'write'},
      {name: 'read'}
    ],
    {  name: 'addr'},
    {  name: 'wdata'},
  ],
  {},
  ['Slave',
    ['ctrl',
      {name: 'ack'},
    ],
    {  name: 'rdata'},
  ]
]}
```

Comment: You can obtain this layout with a simple  `tabular` and the `bigdelim` package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such things can easily be achieved with forest with `where n children=0{tier=murmel}{rotate=90}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
for tree={grow'=0,font=\sffamily,
    where n children=0{tier=murmel}{rotate=90}}
[,phantom
 [clk]
 [Master
  [ctrl
   [write]
   [read]
  ]
  [addr]
  [wdata]
 ]
 [Slave
  [ctrl
  [ack]
  ]
 [rdata]
 ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]